# How i must use rand_r()?

Tags: c, random

It gets me error at rand_r

**undefined reference to 'rand_r'**

It is my first program at c language

I must use rand_r to threads, but i don't know what to do. 
Please help me. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "p3160062.h"

int cook;
int oven;
int prep;
int bake;
pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_t thread_id[100];
unsigned int seed;
int a;

void *myThread(void *vargp)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    a=rand_r(&seed)%6;
    while(a==0){
        a=rand_r(&seed)%6;
    }
    printf("a=%d\n",a);
    sleep(1);
    printf("In thread\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    seed=1;
    int i=0;
    printf("Before Thread\n");
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        pthread_create(&(thread_id[i]), NULL, myThread, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread_id[i], NULL);
        seed++;
    }
    printf("After Thread\n");
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `rand_r` has been deprecated since POSIX.1-2008. I'm not sure what the replacement in C is.

Comment: The POSIX specification of [`rand_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rand_r.html) suggests using the
[`drand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) family of functions, or [`random()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/random.html). The examples after the specification contains a possible implementation for a `rand()`-like function; making that into `rand_r()`-like function should be feasible (though the saved state for the `rand()`-like function is `unsigned long` not `unsigned` like `rand_r()` uses).

Comment: Since you run the 100 threads sequentially — there is no parallelism — you don't need to use `rand_r()`; regular old `rand()` and `srand()` would work fine.  As soon as you fix the code to have the threads run concurrently, you need the separate seed per thread.  The simple upgrade is to use `nrand48()` or `jrand48()`.